# Linear layout weight sum not enforced

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio

I've made a LinearLayout to contain several rows of buttons. To set the maximum number of buttons I can have in the row  I used a weight sum of 6 and a layout weight of 1 for each button so I can have 6 on each row. However, now when I add more buttons they keep getting squeezed in to the same row. Anyone know why it's not looking at the layout weight?
Below is my layout code:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" tools:context=".MainActivity"
android:weightSum="6"
android:clickable="false"
android:orientation="horizontal">


<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/eng1"
    android:id="@+id/eng1"
    android:background="@color/red"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:onClick="displayMessage"
    android:textSize="20dp" />
<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/cowl"
    android:id="@+id/cowl"
    android:textSize="20dp"
    android:background="@color/red"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:onClick="displayMessage"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    android:layout_weight="1" />
<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/DIFFNG"
    android:id="@+id/diffng"
    android:textSize="20dp"
    android:background="@color/red"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:onClick="displayMessage"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    android:layout_weight="1" />
<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/elec"
    android:id="@+id/elec"
    android:background="@color/red"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:textSize="20dp"
    android:onClick="displayMessage"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    android:layout_weight="1" />
<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/battt"
    android:id="@+id/battt"
    android:background="@color/red"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:textSize="20dp"
    android:onClick="displayMessage"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    android:layout_weight="1" />
<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/eng2"
    android:id="@+id/eng2"
    android:background="@color/red"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:textSize="20dp"
    android:onClick="displayMessage"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    android:layout_weight="1" />


</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have have set weight_sum as 6 you can only have 6 sub-childs inside that layout . If you add more than 6 they will be squeezed.

Make this parameter

```
 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
```

in all of your buttons to

```
    android:layout_width="0dp"
```

As if you are using weights in horizontal layout , you need to make width of childs as 0dp .

And height of your LinearLayout as wrap_content .

Comment: Is there no way to make it start a new 'row' using one LinearLayout?

Comment: You need have a different multiple LinearLayout( horizontal ) in a parent LinearLayout ( vertical )  or use GridView .